# How to read a richtextbox lines and put those in to a byte array in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I'm using this code to read lines from a `RichTextBox` control and put in to a string array. But it doesn't work. Gives me an error. Any ideas? Thanks

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Observations.Lines.Length; i++ )
{
    Variables.ObservationsArray [i] = Observations.Lines[i].ToString();
}
```

Comment: What error? Also in your loop you probably want to use `<` instead of `<=` to avoid getting the index out of range exception at runtime. In C# array indexes are zero based.

Comment: Use the "new" keyword to create an object instance

Comment: I think you have just declared Variables.ObservationsArray array!!, you might have to create new instance for each..like Variables.ObservationsArray [i] = new Variables.ObservationsArray (); and then use it!

Comment: It seems it's a string[]. Check which of the objects is null. Observations? Variables? Variables.ObservationsArray? Also, which is the type of what Observations.Lines[i] returns? I'm surprised you have to call ToString().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems here. First there will be an index out of range exception when `i = Observations.Lines.Length` as you are you have stated `i <= Observations.Lines.Length`

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Observations.Lines.Length; i++ )
```

Instead you should do

```
for (int i = 0; i < Observations.Lines.Length; i++ )
```

as array indices are 0 based.

Second, if `Variables.ObservationsArray [i] == null` for any element, you will get a null reference exception. So you should check it first

```
if(Observations.Lines[i] != null
    Variables.ObservationsArray [i] = Observations.Lines[i].ToString();
```

To convert string to a byte array (in case of ASCII encoding) you can use

```
byte[] b2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (myString);
```

Comment: I tried this but still no guys. The exact error is "NullReferenceExeption was unhandled", "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I need help!! thanks!

Comment: @aroshlakshan at what line you are getting this exception?

Comment: In Variables.ObservationsArray [i] = Observations.Lines[i].ToString();

Comment: @aroshlakshan it seems that either "Variables" or "ObservationsArray" is null. you can check it by adding a break point to this line

Comment: Variables is the class that contains the array

Comment: Did a breakpoint in that line and it doesn't contain any info about the ObservationsArray

Comment: @aroshlakshan it means that ObservationsArray is not initialized and is null. you should do like Variables.ObservationsArray [i] = new Variables.ObservationsArray (); or directly assign it another array Variables.ObservationsArray [i] = anotherObervationsArray;

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get a byte[]

```
 System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Join( "", Observations.Lines ));
```